# Qt application with multiple threads

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, pthreads

I have a QT application.

I have a thread (ex **thread1**) that shows my mainwindow (so this is different from the main thread).

I also have my own thread (ex **thread2**) must notify the thread1 updating my GUI.
There is a quick way to do this?
ex: thread2 may decide to update an image: so, he shall notify the thread1 to perform the method `changeImage()`.

If I do run this method directly from thread2 my application will have  a crash.
I must to use pthread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the main thread should update the GUI (for  restrictions due to graphical systems).

However, Qt has enhanced thread support allowed by signal-slot connections across threads. In facts, the other threads have to notify the main thread using signals (`emit my_signal()` see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) or using `QCoreApplication::postEvent`( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent-2 )